# Google Font as substitute font-family not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Here is my problem, I need to set fonts like this:

```
font-family: 'Century Gothic', Helvetica, Dosis;
```

Dosis is font from Google Fonts library. I need that, Century Gothic is MS Font, installed with Office (until 2010), Helvetiva - you all know. So I need third choice.

When I put Dosis in first position it works of course. Second or third position gives me Arial.

I tried loading this font by @import in CSS and  in header. Both doesn't work.

[image: Google Chrome inspector]

As you can see, it all looks just fine, but Rendered font is Arial (why?!). I was thinking about that: Dosis is not loaded at all. But why isn't?

PS. @import and  of course are before that css lines with font-family.

Anybody?

//
I tried:

```
font-family: Helvetica, Dosis;
```

Gives me Arial.

```
font-family: 'Century Gothic', Dosis;
```

Worked! I've got Dosis.

Now I really don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dosis has nothing to do with this (Just to clear things out), It is `Helvetica`. In Google Chrome `Helvetica` is rendered with `Arial` which FYI is the default font for sans-serif for Google Chrome in Windows.
Src: http://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/fonts-and-formatting/web-browser-font-defaults/
But that has nothing much to do either.

All the unrecognized fonts will be rendered with the default Standard font which most of the time is Times New Roman. (Except, of course `Helvetica`)
Since `Helvetica` is metrically identical to `Arial` meaning each character's width in both `Helvetica` and `Arial` is exactly same, it is rendered as `Arial` which helps in displaying and printing text correctly.
     All others are rendered to the Standard font, Times New Roman.

Comment: hm, then why Century Gothic is just ignored and if browser isn't finding CG it's just skipping to the next one font?

It's not just the Google Chrome issue, Internet Explorer does this same thing.

Comment: Because in case of CG, the browser is not able to render and checks for the next one in the font-family like it is expected to do. But in a special case of Helvetica, It knows Arial works in place of Helvetica cuz the above mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned Century gothic font is a MS font and is **NOT** available on Gfonts.
Closest Gfont is [Google font Muli](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Muli)

The second point is that you have to import that font.
Third this is how this works
font-family: 'Century Gothic', Dosis;
First the browser tries to load Century Gothic, if it fails it loads Dorsis.
So why are you getting Arial? It's the browsers default font [Web browsers default fonts](http://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/fonts-and-formatting/web-browser-font-defaults/)

Comment: That fonts are just an example. Client is "Pixel perfect" person, so, if he wants Century Gothic it must be Century Gothic (and all the rest here).

Yep, Why? I still don't know why.

CG + Dosis gave me Dosis.
Helvetica + Dosis gave me Arial. That's crazy and illogical.

Comment: Another option besides Google fonts is to download the font (free od paid) and include it from your server. As for the illogical loading my guess is that your primary and fallback fonts are not loading properly and that's why it goes to arial. Check the other browsers if it's loading the default font or properly loading your desired fonts.

Comment: I tried Chrome, IE, Opera and Firefox. Everytime this same effect.
When first font is Century Gothic that loads. I can also make headlines in Dosis, then put "CG, Helvetica, Dosis", and there is still Arial... (because I don't have CG or Helvetica)

Comment: Ok try to load first some default font like serif sans or smthg and see will it load Arial as primary or that font

Comment: Putting there "Helvetica" gives me Arial. CG + Dosis works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Please include this in your css file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Dosis Regular'), local('Dosis-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dosis/v4/xIAtSaglM8LZOYdGmG1JqQ.woff) format('woff');
}
body{
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: I can't put Dosis in first place in font-family and that the problem.

It didn't worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can put more than one font name in font-family property to be sure, that one of them will be displayed on the screen. But if the browser find first font (in your case 'Century Gothic') it will miss the rest (Helvetica and Dosis).

So, if you prefer Dosis font, please change

```
font-family: 'Century Gothic', Helvetica, Dosis;
```

to this one:

```
font-family: Dosis, Helvetica, 'Century Gothic';
```

Comment: I DO not prefer Dosis.
Dosis is the font that should be on this site ONLY if there is no way to show Century Gothic or Helvetica. It's Google Font, loaded via @font-face, so it will work everywhere. So, NOPE, putting Dosis as a first font is not an option.

Comment: Even the question says Dosis in the first position works, but that is not what is required.

Comment: For now I know, that putting Helvetica in font-family gives "Arial" if not found. If I will put any other font instead of Helvetica there that will work. Good to know, but now I'm really curious why is that happening.